# Rails precompile assets - Cannot access precompiled files locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

I have a mysterious problem in my rails application, which I cannot fix.

The thing is that I want to precompile my CSS and JavaScripts and run the server on the staging environment locally to check if everything is ok, before I deploy to the server.

I run this command to precompile the files:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging
```

To start the server in staging environment i run this command:

```
rails s -e staging
```

The files are being precompiled successfully and placed in the public/assets folder, but can not be loaded in the browser, and I cannot access the files manually from the browser either.

My staging.rb environment file looks like this:

```
 # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true

  # Use a different cache store in production
  #config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211'


  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

In using following versions of ruby and rails:

Ruby v. 1.9.3
Rails v. 3.2.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by outcommenting the line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: remember to `rm -rf public/assets` after testing too, otherwise your development server will load the old precompiled files and ignore recent code changes