# Rails: How Can I save a copy of each of the compiled js/css assets out to a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im working in a Rails 4 app. Is there a way to get each complied js/css file that would be served though "javascript_include_tag" and "stylesheet_link_tag" and copy/save it out to a file elsewhere? I hope that question makes sense.

I can of course go into "app/assets/javascripts" and "app/assets/stylesheets" and copy files from there but application for instance has "require" statements like "//= require jquery" and such that wouldnt be imported because the file isnt processed.

Anyone know how this can be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`rake assets:precompile` will precompile your assets and put them into `public/asssets`.

Comment: Thanks! Is is possible to do this with out a rake task? As in triggered from an action?

Comment: Well, all those asset files will have a URL so when your app is running, you could just download from that URL and it'll either serve your precompiled static assets, all smushed together if you're in production, or it'll process your assets live and give you the result, if your in development. Alternatively, you could code what the asset pipeline does for you yourself.

Comment: What do you want this for?

Comment: The Rake task should get me what I need. What Im trying to do is basically output a static version of a page that can be taken and hosted elsewhere. I'm 95% there. The last part is trying to figure out how to get the result of those processed files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by using the assets precompile script, as suggested by [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20254739/306084)

First edit your `development.rb` environment file to remove the line

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Then run `rake assets:precompile` and you should have a full set of JS and CSS in your `public/assets/` directory.

Comment: Thanks! Is is possible to do this with out a rake task? As in triggered from an action?